# How can I extract only the text out of a list of tuples

Tags: python

I'm writing a code in python, where I need to extract only the text out of this list of tuples :

```
[(u'Don',), (u'Film Songs',), (u'Robin Hood',)]
```

Output I need is just the strings `"Don", "Film Songs", "Robin Hood"`

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: Is the problem getting the first element of each tuple or converting from unicode? (i.e. the u'...')

Comment: I believe in you Darshan - Give it an attempt!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. [5.3 tuples and sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list-comprehension and `join` to obtain strings:

```
>>> lst = [(u'Don',), (u'Film Songs',), (u'Robin Hood',)]
>>> '\n'.join([x[0] for x in lst])
Don
Film Songs                                                 
Robin Hood
```

Comment: Appreciate it!! Thank you, this is working.. but can you please share any other method where in I can use these strings individually to compare with some live data which I will be fetching from another source.

Comment: I cannot explain accurately what should be done because I don't know what the live data is like. I would store these strings in a list, iterate through the list, compare each item in list with live data using `in` operator (like `if .. in ...: `). Do whatever when `if` is `True`. But this may/may not work depending on your case.

Comment: I tried converting the output into a list and getting [u'D', u'o', u'n', u'\n', u'F', u'i', u'l', u'm', u' ', u'S', u'o', u'n', u'g', u's', u'\n', u'R', u'o', u'b', u'i', u'n', u' ', u'H', u'o', u'o', u'd'] I just want these names to be appended to a list, Output like: ['Don','Film Songs','Robin Hood'] didn't find a way how to put them into a list?

Comment: Just do `[x[0] for x in lst]`.

Comment: Thank you so much Austin. This was really very helpful to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the list of tuples using a for loop.

```
my_list = [(u'Don',), (u'Film Songs',), (u'Robin Hood',)]
for item in my_list:
    print(item[0])
```

Of course there are many other solutions, but this particular solution is one of many.

Comment: Actually, those aren't tuples because there are no trailing `,` like in the original post. If you `print(type(tuple))` at each pass, you see those are the `unicode` objects. Hence why extracting the first item of the "tuple" actually gives the first letter of each name. Also, you are redefining the `tuple` Python type in your loop, which could lead to other problems. (From a fresh interpreter the code `print(type(tuple))` would show `<type 'type'>`, not `<type 'unicode'>` as happens in this loop.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply by iterating the *items* of the list and printing the first *index* of the tuple:

```
var = [(u'Don',), (u'Film Songs',), (u'Robin Hood',)]
for item in var:
    print item[0]
```